# Autocompletion for single quotes

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I have for example JS file and I write ", it automatically adds another " and my cursor is between double quotes. Also when i have text and I select the word and on keyboard I press ", it wraps selected word into double quotes, like "word".

I want exact same behavior but for single quotes. Is it possible to make it happen in VS Code? Now when I press single quote on keyboard id doesn't automatically add another single quote for closing string. Also when I select word and press single quote, it replaces selected word instead of wrapping him into single quotes. Any help please?

I tried to set up everything that I found in VS Code to use single quote instead of double quotes, but nothing helped me so far.

Thank you.

Comment: VSCode does this automatically in Javascript files, so you might have installed a plugin that changed this behavior, or you might not be in a Javascript file

Comment: Actually you are right. I use foreign keyboard (non US/UK) and when I type single quote with different keystrokes than I was used to, it suddenly works. Well, thanks.